# Eclipse-Accurev plugin site not working

Tags: accurev

I'm using Eclipse Luna(4.4) version & need to install the Accurev plugin. From the support site below, i used the eclipse plugin site URL as : "http://www.accurev.com/download/eclipseupdate"

Install instructions link: http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/AccuRev/Plugins/Eclipse/2014.1/eclipse-2014.1-install_release_notes-en.pdf

But eclipse throws error saying "Unable to read repository at... " when trying to read/load the plugin. Any one installed Accurev plugin recently?, need your help please!

Spec:
Eclipse : Luna, 4.4
Accurev: 6.1

Thanks,
Somu

Answer (score 1):

With the purchase AccuRev by Microfocus, the AccuRev Web site has since been retired. We are working on having the Eclipse plug-in hosted on the Borland site but this is still a work in progress. It's best that you download the plug-in and self host an update site by accessing the download package at the following URL:

http://supportline.microfocus.com/websync/Tracker.aspx?downl=http://nadownloads.microfocus.com/websync/Internap_Download.aspx?FilePath=/productupdates/accurev/plugins/EclipsePlugin-2014.1/eclipse-2014.1-updatesite.zip

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I'm not clear on the steps. I downloaded just the zip file & put it under /eclipse/plugins dir. It has no effect. Also, tried adding  a Update site in eclipse with the complete url. Still no luck. Can you please let me know how to proceed. Appreciate your help!

Comment: The above links are no longer accessible. I had to make register an account with micro focus. After doing so, I was directed to their support page where I easily found the latest version (may 2015) which has been working well for me (so far).

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved the problem and now I'm able to access the Accurev plugin inside Eclipse:

- Download the .zip plugin from the above link
- Unzip & place the folder ("accurev-eclipse-2014.1-updatesite") under the /eclipse/plugins folder.
- Took couple of eclipse restarts to have the changes reflected in Eclipse